# Weighted average over multiple years

Tags: statistics

If I have five years of data each with the number of employees in each department along with the minimum salary (see below), I know I can do a standard weighted average for each year; however, what if I want to do an average minimum salary for the whole five years? Would I do a weighted average of each year independently and then do a simple average of the weighted averages, or would I have to do a weighted average of the weighted averages? Also, what if I wanted to do it by department per year as well? Would I use the number of employees and minimum salary for each year to do the weighted average?

The data for one year looks like this:

| Department | Min Salary |
| --- | --- |
| 118 | 25,834 |
| 375 | 22,356 |
| 235 | 26,519 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order does not change anything you can either

- Compute the weighted average in one year. Then take the five average, sum them and divide by 5.
- For each department average over the five years, and then do a weighted average over the departments.

Comment: Thanks the first makes sense but not sure what you mean by the second?

Comment: For each department you compute the average minimum salary over the five years, and then you average the five averages.